# JSONRPC with Grails

Tags: grails, web-applications, json-rpc

I am developing an application using Grails 2.3.8 with Java 7. I am brand new to Grails and I am still learning (after years of Django and Pyramid). While it seems really easy to make a RESTful service with Grails, most of the things I have done in the past utilized the protocol known as [JSONRPC 2](http://www.json-rpc.org).

Can anybody show how to either integrate jsonrpc4j with Grails or another way to make a JSONRPC-endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at some existing JSON-based Grails plugins:

https://grails.org/plugins/tag/json

You might be able to take one of these and produce your own custom JSON output format - that is valid JSONRPC2.

Otherwise, its a matter of simply creating a DTO object (simple Groovy bean with the structure matching the JSONRPC2 output), populating the DTO from your domain objects(s) and doing a `render myDto as JSON` in your controller (Grails will do the marshalling to JSON for you).